# Unresolved Promise Assistance Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, aws-lambda

I have the following code below, which is a lambda function to get content from a s3Object zip file.  I know for a fact that I am not resolving the list of promises and need a little direction on how to resolve.  I have read several codes on here but having a hard time applying it to my code.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
// dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var JSZip = require('jszip');

// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // Read options from the event parameter.

    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

    // Download the file from the S3 source bucket. 

    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        };
      const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
      var zip  = JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body).then(function (content){
                  return content;
      });
      zip.then(function(result){
     
      var entries  = Object.keys(result.files).map(function (name) {
                      if(name.indexOf("TestStatus") != -1){ 
                      return name;
                      }
                   }).filter(notUndefined => notUndefined !== undefined);
    
     var listOfPromises = entries.map(function(entry) {
                           return result.file(entry).async("text").then(function(fileContent){
                               return fileContent;
                               
                           });
                         });

      Promise.all(listOfPromises).then((values) =>{
          values.forEach(function(value){
             console.log(value);
          });
      });
      }); 
     
    } catch (error) {
        context.fail(error);
        return;
    }  
   
   
    
};
```

**Modified/Corrected code**

```
// dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var JSZip = require('jszip');


// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // Read options from the event parameter.

    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

    // Download the file from the S3 source bucket. 

    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        };
      const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
      var zip  = JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body);
      return zip.then(function(result){
     
      var entries  = Object.keys(result.files).map((name) =>{
                      if(name.indexOf("TestStatus") != -1){ 
                      return result.files[name];
                      }
                   }).filter(notUndefined => notUndefined !== undefined);
    
     var listOfPromises = entries.map((entry) => {
                           return entry.async("text")
                           .then((u8) => {
                               return [entry.name, u8];
                           }).catch(error => console.error(error));
                          });

     var promiseOfList = Promise.all(listOfPromises);

    
     promiseOfList.then(function (list) {
         console.log(list.toString());
});
});
    
} catch (error) {
        context.fail(error);
        return;
    }  
   
    
};
```

Comment: Don't use `then()`, use `await`.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I am not resolving the list of promises*"? What exactly is the problem, where are you getting an unresolved promise? And where in your code do you actually try to send a response (or return a value?) from your `handler`?

Answer (score -1):

If you look closely you are not retuning anything it is why it stays on Pending

````js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var JSZip = require('jszip');

// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // Read options from the event parameter.

    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));

    // Download the file from the S3 source bucket. 

    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        };
      const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
// here is the problem 
     // var zip  = JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body).then(function (content){
  //                return content;
    //  }

var zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(data.body)

return zip.then(function(result){
     
      var entries  = Object.keys(result.files).map(function (name) {
                      if(name.indexOf("TestStatus") != -1){ 
                      return name;
                      }
                   }).filter(notUndefined => notUndefined !== undefined);
    
     var listOfPromises = entries.map(function(entry) {
                           return result.file(entry).async("text").then(function(fileContent){
                               return fileContent;
                               
                           });
                         });
     console.log("Helo");
      Promise.all(listOfPromises).then((values) =>{
          values.forEach(function(value){
             console.log(value);
          });
      });
      }); 
     
    } catch (error) {
        context.fail(error);
        return;
    }  
   
   
    
};
    ```
````

Comment: This didn't resolve the promises.  The promises that are unresolved or in the variable listOfPromises.

Comment: Actually, I kept your code and realized that I wasn't resolving the promises because  this line result.file(entry).async("text").then(function(fileContent) the result into anything.  I corrected that part  and the code works fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Using `zip = await …` and then afterwards calling `zip.then(…)` cannot work.